# Removing the [data-change] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[data-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-change) has 21 questions, no usage guidance, and is pretty much all over the place - questions on changed data in web statistic software, Excel, Java class variables etc. Each of these things has its own tag and data-change does not seem to provide any added value.

If I understand the process correctly 21 questions do not warrant a formal burninate procedure, so unless there is any <s>violent</s> strongly expressed disagreement here I would edit out the tag over the next few days.

Comment: I think the be nice policy would discourage any sort of _violent disagreement_ :p

Answer (score 12):

Agreed. This tag seems to be about any situation where data is different in one moment from what it was in another moment. Such a tag is exceedingly broad, and of the handful of users who have asked or answered such questions, no one has done so more than once. The tag also has zero followers.

Combine all that with the fact that there are only a handful of questions and the fact that there's never been an attempt at describing the tag in the wiki, it's ripe for removal and auto-deletion from the site after the fact.

As a reminder, when you go through removing the tags, you should also edit/vote appropriately on the questions that need it; don't just go through and kill the tag with no other changes. If there are grammar errors in the posts, or if they are off-topic or otherwise close-worthy, take care of those things in addition to the tag. That shouldn't be too big an ask for such a small pool of questions.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like all of them were retagged as there were only 9 when I first loaded it (I have a CV still pending on one)

At any rate, all the questions are gone now, so burninated!